Taking trace of a tensor product of matrix-valued smooth functions on the thin diagonal
Let $V$ be a finite dimensional real / complex vector space and consider the space $L(V,V)$ of linear operators on $V$.
Fix $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and let $\mathcal{M}$ be the real / complex vector space of smooth functions $F : \mathbb{R}^n \to L(V,V)$.
Then, $\mathcal{M}$ may be given the Frechet topology of uniform convergence of all derivatives on any compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ in analogy to $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Here, I am not specifying the norm to be used on $V$ or $L(V,V)$ etc, because on a finite dimensional vector space, all norms are equivalent.
Fix $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and let $F_1, \cdots, F_k \in \mathcal{M}$. Then we may define a scalar-valued smooth mapping on $\mathbb{R}^n$ by
$$
x \in \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathrm{Tr}\Bigl( F_1(x) \cdots F_k(x)\Bigr) 
$$
We denote such mapping simply as $\mathrm{Tr}\Bigl( F_1 \cdots F_k\Bigr)$.
Next, consider the $k$-fold tensor product space $[\mathcal{M}]^{\otimes k}$ and the mapping
$$
F_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes F_k \in [\mathcal{M}]^{\otimes k} \to \mathrm{Tr}\Bigl( F_1 \cdots F_k\Bigr) \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)
$$
Here, my question is as follows:

In analogy to linear extension in finite dimensions, I suspect that the above mapping can be uniquely extended to a continuous linear map from $[\mathcal{M}]^{\otimes k}$ to $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$. However, I do not see how to find or even define a "basis" for $\mathcal{M}$ to prove this.

Could anyone please help me?
Add) As pointed out in the comment below, $\mathcal{M}$ is a nuclear Frechet space and therefore we can have some sensible topology on $[\mathcal{M}]^{\otimes k}$ according to the Wikipedia article here.

@OrangeMushroom You mean the universal property of a tensor product? In terms of topology, I think I already specified a Frechet one for $\mathcal{M}$, which I believe makes it into a nuclear TVS. So, I think there is a sensible (or standard?) topology on $[\mathcal{M}]^{\otimes k}$ according to here.

Doesn't continuity of the trace, multiplication map and $F$'s allow you to deduce continuity of your map?

@NDewolf Showing continuity of the trace is not as trivial as it originally seemed to me, as the tensor product of Frechet spaces is not simple. I believe that the same caution is needed for the "co-located" multiplication map.

@NDewolf I think that everything must be true, but not too straightforward.

But the trace acts pointwise, where it is continuous

@NDewolf My question is about continuity of the mapping between function spaces?

I know, and I understand the confusion I created. I just meant that the whole construction essentially only uses pointwise operations. So boundedness/continuity should still be a viable route

@NDewolf I see. Thank you for your comment.
